# ng-show if filtered array contains

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cant find a way to show an html-element only if an array contains a particular value among its objects.
So if I have:

```
people[
    {
        id:1, name: 'frank', type: 'good'
        ,id:2, name: 'john', type: 'bad'
        ,id:3, name: 'mary', type: 'good'
    }
]
```

I would like to show some kind of heading for the types.
So if the types are:

```
"great"
"good"
"bad"
```

with the array above, the heading for "great" should not be visible.

I have tried with both ngif and ngshow. Problem seems to be about syntax.
The last one I tried is:

```
(people|filter:(type:'great'))
```

But I get an error in the console.

Is it possible to fix it directly in the html or should I rely on the controller for this kind of operation?

Comment: Why not use `not` in `ng-show` expression? Example: `people.type != 'great'`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xQBqLLhSDT2dhPrhVSWS?p=preview

Comment: I don't think the question is how to use Angular filters, @kazupooot, but rather how to make a decision based on the results of a filtered array. OP, can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your example "array" is badly formed, I'm assuming you meant:

```
people = [
    { id:1, name: 'frank', type: 'good' },
    { id:2, name: 'john',  type: 'bad' },
    { id:3, name: 'mary',  type: 'good' }
];
```

Second, your questions is a bit confusing, but I'm assuming you want to show each person under a header corresponding to their type, and hide headers with no people. Try this:

```
<div ng-if="$filter('filter')(people,{type:'great'}).length > 0">
    <h1>Great</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{type:'great'}">{{person.name}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-if="$filter('filter')(people,{type:'good'}).length > 0">
    <h1>Good</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{type:'good'}">{{person.name}}</p>
</div>
```

You can improve this by creating a second array like:

```
types = [
    { id: 'great', header: 'Great' },
    { id: 'good',  header: 'Good' },
    { id: 'bad',   header: 'Bad' }
];
```

And then just nest your repeats:

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types" ng-if="$filter('filter')(people,{type:type.id}).length > 0">
    <h1>{{type.header}}</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{type:type.id}">{{person.name}}</p>
</div>
```

- Note that I haven't tested this code, only looked it over. It probably includes bugs, but the method should work.
- You will need to add $filter as a dependency of your controller, and inject it

The TL/DR is: **the $filter service allows you to use Angular filters in JS expressions. The 'filter' filter returns an array, so filter your people and check the length.**